# Read from a text file using link list

Tags: c, linked-list, file-handling

Trying to read a text file using this codes.  Why doesn't it display anything?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 100
typedef struct head{
    int total;
    char quest[SIZE],quest1[SIZE],quest2[SIZE],quest3[SIZE];
    struct head *next;
    }LIST;

int main(){
    LIST *ch;
    FILE *fp=fopen("File.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("File doesn't exist");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->total);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->quest);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->quest1);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->quest2);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->quest3);
    }
    printf("%s",ch->total);
    printf("%s",ch->quest);
    printf("%s",ch->quest1);
    printf("%s",ch->quest2);
    printf("%s",ch->quest3);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
4
Programming
Stack
Linked List
Pointer Structure
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you. .

Comment: Please provide at least first lines of file "File,txt"

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->total);` is wrong — you need `%d` (and `printf("%s",ch->total);` needs `%d` too).  Then 
       `fscanf(fp,"%s",&ch->quest);` is wrong too; you don't need the `&` — ditto for the other strings.  You should check each `fscanf()` call to ensure it succeeded.

Comment: first line is - 4
2nd line    - Programming
3rd line     - Stack
4rth line    - Linked List
last line     - Pointer Structure

Comment: Please [edit] and use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to provide the content of the textfile in a more useful way.

Comment: Does the program end in segfault or is there any other error message? It seems much more likely than the program running smoothly while not outputting anything.

Comment: what the output format is also a textfile @YuriGinsburg

Comment: there is no any error message, i think im calling them incorrectly thats why it doesn't display anything @Yunnosch

Comment: How exactly are you calling it? Commandline? IDE? Did you try inserting a `printf("I am actually running.\n");` or other methods of debugging your program?

Comment: Note that the `%s` format for `scanf()` reads a single 'word' — so you'll get `Linked` and `List` read into `quest2` and `quest3`.  I've told you how to fix the problems I spotted.  One of the answers (the only one as I type), identifies another problem (no memory allocated for `ch` to point at).  Your print formatting will run all the data together because there's no spacing in the formats, and you should end the output with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small flaw in the question code.

```
int main(){
    LIST *ch;
```

The variable ch is a pointer, but where it points is a problem.  Basically, it could be pointing to any memory location available to the process.  It is important to set this pointer, so that it points to a suitable memory location.  For example, the malloc() function could be used to allocate a suitable memory location.  For example:

```
int main(){
    LIST *ch = malloc(sizeof(*ch));
```

Here is a an alternate version of the question code that might work better:

file.txt:

```
  4
  Programming
  Stack
  Linked_List
  Pointer_Structure
```

New code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    #define SIZE 100

    typedef struct head{
      int total;
      char quest[SIZE],quest1[SIZE],quest2[SIZE],quest3[SIZE];
      struct head *next;
      }LIST;

    int main()
      {
      int rCode=EXIT_SUCCESS;
      LIST *ch = NULL;

      FILE *fp=fopen("File.txt","r");
      if(!fp)
        {
        rCode=errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed.  errno[%d]\n", rCode);
        goto CLEANUP;
        }

      ch = malloc(sizeof(*ch));
      if(!ch)
        {
        rCode=errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed. errno[%d]\n", rCode);
        goto CLEANUP;
        }

      fscanf(fp,"%d", &ch->total); // %d, not %s, as per Jonathan Leffler
      fscanf(fp,"%s",ch->quest);   // Notice that &ch->quest was changed to ch->quest
      fscanf(fp,"%s",ch->quest1);  //   "      "     "        "     "     "    "
      fscanf(fp,"%s",ch->quest2);  //   "      "     "        "     "     "    "
      fscanf(fp,"%s",ch->quest3);  //   "      "     "        "     "     "    "

      printf("%d\n", ch->total); // %d, not %s, as per Jonathan Leffler
      printf("%s\n",ch->quest);
      printf("%s\n",ch->quest1);
      printf("%s\n",ch->quest2);
      printf("%s\n",ch->quest3);

    CLEANUP:

      if(ch)
        free(ch);

      if(fp)
        fclose(fp);

      return(rCode);
      }
```

Output:

```
  4
  Programming
  Stack
  Linked_List
  Pointer_Structure
```

Comment: Can you use that to explain the absence of output?

Comment: Thank you for the code its already running, but there's still some problems, the output doesn't displaying as what i am expecting.

Comment: whats the use of errno?

Comment: @Angel, functions like fopen() and malloc() return NULL if they fail.  It is important to know the reason for the failure in order to correct the problem; so these functions, when they fail, place a code in the global "errno" variable to indicate why the failure occurred.  For example, if malloc() is called, but no memory is available, malloc() will return NULL, and then set errno to ENOMEM.  (See documentation for malloc())